# What is state provider and root provider which library file will include it

Tags: angularjs

Hi friends i am beginner for angularjs what is state provider and root provider why we inject ['ngRoute'] in rooteProvider and ['ui.router'] in stateprovider i'm really confused this so please explain briefly which library file include root and state provider in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about it first then ask questions about your issues:-

Here are few links, check them out

Information:

Github: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
Documentation:

API Reference: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api
   Guide: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

FAQs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions
Sample Application: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

> ngRoute is a angular core module which is good for basic scenarios. I
>   believe that they will add more powerful features in upcoming
>   releases.

URL: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

You will get detail information from this link, go through it - 
[Angular JS ui-router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)